# How to init stores data with react fast?

Tags: optimization, reactjs, flux

How to init data fast in react??

In my project, we make client react app.

I'm using `alt(flux)`, `normalizr`, `immutable`. And to optimize performance, I'm using `PureRendermixin` with immutalbejs.

When user navigates page, each store listens to the browser location and gets ALL data through ajax, initializes itself with the data it needs.

After that, each store fires `emitChange`, react re-renders component tree.

But, the problem is firing `emitChange` in all essential bootstrapped stores re-renders component tree.
This makes it so slow even browser gets frozen.

i.e. user clicks a link and bootstraps page data to stores (bootstrapping). In
this case updated DOMAIN store data (Posts, Comments, Lists, Paginates, Users, Categories... more than 10 stores for dependency in view component. Look at the picture so many lifecycle, emitchanges, rerendering updates ) is requested and merge updated.

- NODE_ENV=dev
  [image]
  This takes more than 1 sec, and browser stops
- NODE_ENV=prod
  [image]
  This takes more than 200ms, even better but not enough to use.

How to optimize architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use server-rendering technique (universal / isomorphic), and pass data from server directly to clientside without Ajax.

Comment: I came from server-redering. Because that was slower